# How to make orderby filter work on array of strings?

Tags: angularjs

Here is the code which is not working: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8dt94/63/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
  <ul ng-repeat="strVal in arrVal|orderBy|filter:searchText" >
      <li>{{strVal}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope,$filter) {
  $scope.arrVal = ['one','two','three','four','five','six'];  
});
```

Comment: I do not believe you should be using primitive values in your ng-repeat array.  If not it works. (http://jsfiddle.net/EGVwG/).

Comment: This question still applies to the ng-options attr of a select, which must be a list of strings.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You can order by a method, so you can use the toString method

```
<ul ng-repeat="strVal in arrVal | orderBy:'toString()' | filter:searchText">
```

Comment: +1. Additionally you can add "track by" to the end:

<ul ng-repeat="strVal in arrVal | orderBy:'toString()' | filter:searchText track by $index">

Comment: Great solution, I needed an array of numbers sorted like this `[2,5,3,1,6, 33]` so instead f `toString()` I used `valueOf()` and it worked perfect. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: This worked for me too! Any idea why this trick works though?

Answer (score 12):

Write a [custom filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters):

```
app.filter('mySort', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return input.sort();
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="strVal in arrVal|filter:searchText|mySort">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/5PJrr/).