# orderBy over simple array?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array like this:

```
$scope.telcodes = ['44', '01', '221', '335'];
```

How do I use orderBy on a simple array like this to produce an ordered list starting from 01?

I know how to do this on an array containing objects but not on simple arrays like the above.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="telcode in telcodes | orderBy:????:false track by $index">
```

Comment: From a comment on http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/#!/api/ng.filter:orderBy    -   Use orderBy: 'toString()' to sort an array of strings. These docs assume you're sorting an array of objects which is not always what you need. - Of course if you are sorting numbers you'll need to use Number() instead.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - if you add this as an answer to the question, you will get credited for it!  Your solution is much simpler than the other two answers.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493116/how-to-make-orderby-filter-work-on-array-of-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare simple `proxy` function within your controller and use it:

Controller:

```
$scope.proxy = function(x) { return x; }
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in telcodes | orderBy: proxy">
```

However, it gives you string comparison ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcp9c/)).

To get standard numeric comparison modify `proxy` a little ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcp9c/1/)):

```
$scope.proxy = function(x) { return x * 1; }
```

Answer (score 3):

`<tr ng-repeat="t in telcodes | orderBy>` should be all you need

Answer (score 2):

This was curious.

Here is the shortest solution I could come up with: http://plnkr.co/edit/WsofTTYIGa2OSuTsJCKd

**Controller**

```
$scope.id = function (d) { return d; }; // return +d; if you want numeric sort.
```

**Template**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in arr | orderBy:id:false">{{item}}</li>
```