# complicated custom sorting in nested array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've problem sorting my nested array, says I've json like this

```
var orders = [{
    'orderId': 1,
        'sales': [{
        'salesNumbers': 3
    }]
}, {
    'orderId': 2,
        'sales': [{
        'salesNumbers': 4

    }]
}];
```

and I wish I can sort orderId base on salesNumbers. You may say it's impossible or I made a mistake by putting sales as array but it contain only 1 object which is salesNumbers. That's not a mistake, I just do not want to simplify my problem.

so it's possible to, without changing the data structure, sort orderId base on salesNumbers?? My app demo http://jsfiddle.net/sq2C3/

Comment: "I just do not want to simplify my problem" -- why would you NOT want to simplify it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. it's just like sorting any other Array of Objects. You just need to target the nested object/field to sort on.

Comment: @RUJordan because it's so complicated and tons of code to post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say the `sales` array only has one item in it, you can order by `salesNumbers` like this:

```
orderBy:'sales[0].salesNumbers'
```

Here is an update of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/sq2C3/2/

Comment: you saved my life, I knew nothing is impossible!

Comment: just curious hw angular know which sales I refer to? I mean I can have sales in somewhere of my json too

Comment: orderBy can only see properties on the `order` object created by ng-repeat.

Comment: thanks. I found my problem still haven't solve, what if I've multiple item in my sales array? I can't do loop in <li>

Comment: you mean you want to sort the orders by their max salesNumbers, not the first one?  for that i believe you will need a custom filter, or presort your data in the controller.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493116/how-to-make-orderby-filter-work-on-array-of-strings