# orderBy:' ' , in angularjs not working, what is the error?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-orderby

I am trying to sort the array using orderBy:names, but its not working , can some one tell me where i am doing the mistake??

```
<body data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="controller1" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchbox" />
        <li ng-repeat="name in names|filter:searchbox|orderBy:'names'">
            {{name}}
        </li>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app=angular.module('app', []).controller('controller1', ['$scope', function($scope){

      $scope.names=['david', 'shreya', 'ankit'];

    }]);
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by the toString() method.  See: [How to make orderby filter work on array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493116/how-to-make-orderby-filter-work-on-array-of-strings).  From that answer:

```
<ul ng-repeat="strVal in arrVal | orderBy:'toString()' | filter:searchText">
```