# Order json array alphabetically in angular.js when there is no key/value association

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to alphabetize a list based on a json array, but I cant seem to get it to work. My current code looks like this. Here is a link to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hxxLaxL3/

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="f in friends | orderBy:'f'">{{f}}</li>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.friends =
      ['C',
      'B',
      'Z',
      'S'];
}
```

Output

- C
- B
- Z
- S

Desired Output

- B
- C
- S
- Z

Comment: `$scope.friends = ['C', 'B', 'Z', 'S'].sort();` is probably easiest

Comment: orderBy:'toString()'

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493116/how-to-make-orderby-filter-work-on-array-of-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `orderBy:'f'` to `orderBy:'toString()'`

```
    <div ng-app>
      <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <li ng-repeat="f in friends | orderBy:'toString()'">{{f}}</li>      
      </div>
    </div>
```